# Mostrar Reportes Teleriks en proyecto asp mvc da error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendoui, reportviewer

Buenas tardes, tengo un proyecto en asp mvc 5, con vistas razor, el cual estoy tratando de mostrar unos reportes de teleriks que ya tengo hechos, y se encuentran en la carpeta Content, sin embargo me esta dando muchos problemas y errores.

Como este:
**Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=7.0.13.220, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado tratando de seguir los pasos de este tutorial

http://www.telerik.com/blogs/telerik-reporting-in-mvc-sure-it-takes-8-quick-steps-

Aqui esta mi web config, en la parte de handlers

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <remove name="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd_*"/>
      <add name="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd_*" path="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd" verb="*" type ="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler, Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=7.0.13.220, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Y la parte de la vista que he estado tratando de configurar sin exito (Añadi en la raiz del proyecto un asp webform, para que trabajara con aspx)

```
<%@ Import Namespace="SSMS_2._0._1.Content" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=7.0.13.220, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" namespace="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms" tagprefix="telerik" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Telerik.Reporting, Version=7.0.13.220, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be"
namespace="Telerik.Reporting" tagprefix="telerik" %>


<form id="main" method="post" action="">
 <telerik:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" Width="100%" Height="800px" runat="server">
 </telerik:ReportViewer>
</form>

<script runat="server">
 public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
  {
 // to avoid the server form (<form runat="server"> requirement
  }
 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
 base.OnLoad(e);
      var instanceReportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
      instanceReportSource.ReportDocument = new Dashboard();
      ReportViewer1.ReportSource = instanceReportSource;
  }
</script>
```

Hasta aca he llegado y llevo dias buscando la solucion, cualquier ayuda seria bien recibida, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debia hacer, era actualizar el proyecto con las herramientas de teleriks, lo cual envio todos los recursos necesarios para que se viera el reportviewer, sin embargo, ahora tengo problemas con los parametros, aqui la otra pregunta, para cerrar esta

[Como agregar parametros a un reportviewer telerik por codigo ya que el asistente no funciona](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7451/como-agregar-parametros-a-un-reportviewer-telerik-por-codigo-ya-que-el-asistente)

Answer (score 0):

Deber validar que la dll `Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll` se encuentre en la carpeta `bin` del sitio web donde realizas el deploy.

Si revisas la documentacion de Telerik lo menciona

[Deploying Web Applications](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/installation-deploying-on-web-application)

> During the installation of Telerik Reporting on your machine, the Telerik assemblies were added to GAC. When deploying a Web Application project the assemblies from the GAC are not copied automatically so you need to make sure the assemblies physically exist in the bin folder of your application

---

Ademas podrias validar que la opcion `Copy Local` de la dll este en `true`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se que en la imagen veras otras dll, pero es solo un ejemplo para que encuentres a opcion a la cual hago referencia.